# Stored Procedure vs Service output xml/json

Tags: web-services, stored-procedures

Our company is recommending services for everything.

So during requirements implementation meeting, I was asked why services are recommended to existing stored procedure.

They want to use stored procedure directly and doesn't want to call services that internally calls the same store procedure.

Their argument was how will web request handle large amount of data and stored procedure are faster than services.

My only argument was services can be exposed to anyone and can be used externally too.

I told them we can use pagination technique to break down request that expects large amount of data as response to multiple requests. They were not convinced.

Do you have any more reasons?

Comment: so any luck? Manage to convince them?

Comment: How did this turn out? Also, posting this in programmers.stackexchange.com could get many more answers.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  They are going with web services approach, where Websphere Message Broker will be used to develop services that will call store procedures.

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to software quality.

Good Software quailty should cover these points:

1. Readability
2. Maintainability
3. Efficeiency
4. Security, Exception and error handling
5. Testability

I think you will find stored procedures won't be able to cover all these points and well as managed code with a good source control. Services especially advantageous when running one big long calculation call to the db.

Stepping through with a debugger is always also very valuable in my opinion.

However - If there not worried about these points of software quality then there is advantages in running a calculation right next to the data in terms of performance, especially if there is many calls to the db(less overhead in connections). Also the solution could be more simple with no overhead of compilation and service set up.

Comment: Well, I don' think most of them care about first 4 things. THey want things to be done. For my question, how to hanlde large amount of data via service, what do you recommend

Comment: If there not worried about these points then there is advantages in running a calculation right next to the data, your will gain a lot of performance. - I'll add this to my answer

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons but the applicability will differ on the problem domain. If the users are familiar with stored procedures and If there are no client applications, no user interfaces, no requirement for multiple data views etc then there would not be enough arguments to vote against directly using a stored  procedure.

In general services provide the following benefits. You need to judge whether they are applicable to your requirements:

1. Support multiple Clients, Views.
2. Define a transaction boundary.
3. A place to map the data from the format stored in db to domain objects, considering DAO/ORM part of the services layer and not the stored procedure.
4. Bundle business logic/rules.
5. Underlying data source changes will not affect the consumers/views.
6. Better logging.
7. Options for filtering/proxying.
8. A layer for loadbalancing, caching etc.

And many more.